# How do I apply CSS to a table (borders) in KotlinJS/React using kotlin-styled?

Tags: css, kotlin, kotlin-js

The following is a code sample of a table component I was playing with

```
import csstype.BorderCollapse.Companion.collapse
import kotlinx.css.border
import react.*
import react.dom.*
import styled.*

external interface BidTableProps : PropsWithChildren {
    var b: List<MyProps>
}
val TableComponent = functionComponent<MyProps> { props ->
    p {
        +"Table below"
    }
    styledTable {
        css {
            border = "1px solid black"
            collapse
        }
        styledThead {
            tr {
                th { +"a_header" }
                th { +"b_header" }
                th { +"c_header" }
            }
        }
        tbody {
            for (b in props.obj) {
                tr {
                    td { +b.a.toString() }
                    td { +b.b }
                    td { +b.c }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    p {
        +"Table above"
    }
}
```

I see an enclosing box around the table but the cells are not divided or the border is not applied to the cells. How do I apply the border correctly to all cells of the table? Bonus: Any good documentation on using kotlin-styled wrapper?

kotlin-styled -> https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/tree/master/kotlin-styled

Comment: You need to apply this style of `border` to all `td` elements of a table, not a `table` itself

Comment: I guess I cant do that in Kotlin code without repeating the `style{}` inside each `td` element right? or is there another way?

Comment: Yes, in CSS you may use a descendant combinator for this (`table tr { border = ... }`). In kotlin-styled it could be done with `styledTable { css { descendants("tr") { border = "1px solid black" } ... } ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said @Михаил-Нафталь mentioned above adding the following to the `css` block does the job

```
css {
    descendants( "th", "td") {
        border = "1px solid black"
    }
    borderCollapse = BorderCollapse.collapse
}
```